# How to get settings in middleware?

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm sure this has got to be a duplicate, but I've been searching way too long and still can't find the answer.

I want to access configuration options (from a json file, although I don't think the source matters in regard to my question) from here:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.Run(async context =>
        {
            // Get my config values here and do something with them
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    }
```

I could use `var x = Config.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:MySetting:0");` but because it's a list I would have to create a loop and retrieve values until I get a null value and all that so I would rather do the IOptions thing so it loads it in a strongly typed class for me. I have this code in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Config.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

but I just don't know how to get at the object that's registered there from within the Configure method.

I also tried inspecting the value of `Config.GetSection("AppSettings")` while debugging and found that under the json provider I could see my settings. However, while that's available in the inspector, I can't see how I can directly access my list. That is, I can access my list one value at a time using GetValue() but I can't just access the whole list as one value.

Answer (score 0):

As often seems to happen, I finally figured out what I was looking for right after making a post here. Basically, I don't need IOptions or anything else having to do with DI for my scenario. I just needed to use `.Bind()` to bind the settings to an instance of my class:

```
AppSettings a = new AppSettings();
Config.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(a);
```

Comment: Kind of strange they don't have a generic overload that takes a type setting of the class. That would have been super obvious.

Comment: try `var a= Config.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>() ;`

Comment: I think I did and got null. I will test it out tomorrow to be sure though. Thanks!

Comment: I just tested that. I'm now pretty sure it works if you write the class of `AppSettings` correctly.